# Add feature to Fuse container

Tags: java, pom.xml, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I'm trying to add my feature to the container. I create testpool profile and add my local repository `(file:C:/jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/system/np-dbcp-feature/MyFeaturesRepo/xml/features/features.xml)`. After that I see available features from my repository (np-dbcp-feature).  When I try to add my profile to the container I receive Provision Status:

```
Provision Exception Trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical 
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418) 
    at org.fusesource.fabric.agent.ObrResolver.createResource(ObrResolver.java:270) 
    at org.fusesource.fabric.agent.ObrResolver.resolve(ObrResolver.java:108) 
    at     org.fusesource.fabric.agent.DeploymentAgent.updateDeployment(DeploymentAgent.java:566) 
    at org.fusesource.fabric.agent.DeploymentAgent.doUpdate(DeploymentAgent.java:432) 
    at org.fusesource.fabric.agent.DeploymentAgent$1.run(DeploymentAgent.java:242) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What is wrong? Which one URI is not hierarchical?
features.xml and pom.xml files are here (sorry, but I can post only 2 links):
http://pastebin.com/4D7i7UQQ

I'm trying to do something like that http://fusesource.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=8619 but for mssql.

Upd: I've commented my bundles in features.xml and I had no exceptions, so the problem is somewhere in my bundles' pom.xml files

Comment: Is it possible to show the features.xml and make sure all your bundles are installed in maven repository before installing features to FUSE

Answer (score 0):

The URI prefix `file:D:/` does not look right, try with `file:///D:/` instead.